# How REST is "lightweight"?

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I have been seeing SOAP is "Heavy Weight" and REST is "Light Weight". On what parameters, we are telling REST is lightweight than SOAP?

We were using IFW model web services in our company earlier. But our management told us to develop all the new APIs going forward in REST. We are backend service providers in my company.

How REST is best useful for us?

What does "lightweight" means in context?

This question seems like repetition but don't understand the terms used.

Comment: REST uses less resources in my opinion. REST can return xml or json response which is easier to parse and there is no need for libraries for parsing SOAP response. You should be able to find videos in youtube that explain the difefrence between the two

Comment: SOAP has XML like structure which requires starting as well as ending tags, thus increasing the network load as they have to travel over the network ,which is not the case with REST. This is 1 of the many reasons..

Comment: You can send compressed json as response, which further reduces the bandwidth. I think browsers can natively uncompress such responses.

Comment: yeah but that is one of the "many" cases..

Answer (score 11):

REST gives you a session less window into a system. It does not track you, it does not care about you. All you have done is send a request which contains..hopefully some id to verify that you can make it. It may return a HTTP status code, it may return some body but ultimately, once the request is complete you are forgotten.

SOAP is heavy in a sense that it describes a "contract" between the remote system and your client. In order for your client to communicate effectively it MUST implement its schema...this is the SOAP skeleton. It describes the calls you can make and the objects you can expect back.

The reason why SOAP is heavy is because of serialization. Upon each SOAP request you typically serialize a java object, send it over HTTP and get a serialized response which is deserialized into an object via reflection...this is heavy. It also means that if the endpoint changes how they work, you must change your contract. You don't have to do this with REST.

With SOAP you run into multi threaded issues.

To answer quickly..

they might mean that a REST service is "lightweight" because you do not need to release changes to clients. You simply make changes to your logic, retaining URLS and the response should remain the same.

With SOAP...if you added a new field to an object, you would have to get the client to implement the new schema. SOAP is pretty old had.

Comment: Even in REST, if we are adding new fields in XML, client needs to be aware rite?

Comment: Tricky one. If you are adding child elements or even parent elements then no. But you if you change the name of an element/attribute that they are expecting then yes..they will need to implement a change.

Comment: To elaborate. The good thing about REST is it allows you to do this kind of thing. You can expand (without renaming elements/attributes) an XML response as much as you want. It wont break the client's system..only enable them to expand it if and when they're ready.

Comment: But you should be client conscious when making your changes. Make sure that the data they expected from the SOAP service is still there in the body of the REST service response. Moving from SOAP to REST will require changes on both sides...regardless.

Comment: I was trying to implement this new field addition in SOAP service. I created one add service which will add two numbers. I created client using that wsdl. Then i have changed wsdl to accept 3 numbers and generated the service. But i didnt regenerate the client. But after deploy, even though client is not aware of that 3rd field, it works well, it doesnt break the code. It sends 2 numbers and get correct response back. Why SOAP clients needs to notified if we add new field in the wsdl.?

Comment: By field do you mean function parameter? Is the old function, accepting two numbers still there in your server code?

Comment: Thinking about it further, I'm guessing reflection is to blame. If you are using int primitives and not Integers in the method signature, the third parameter would default to 0. Try changing your server side code to use the Integer class rather than primitive. Check the resulting WSDL to make sure

Comment: i tried, but the same behavior. I verified the server class, it has only one method with three parameters. And client has only one method with two parameters. I'm not sure how they are communicating.

Answer (score 2):

REST is lightweight in that it and relies upon the HTTP standard to do its work. It is great to get a useful web service up and running quickly. If you don't need a strict API definition, this is the way to go. Most web services fall into this category. You can version your API so that updates to the API do not break it for people using old versions(as long as they specify a version). REST essentially requires HTTP and is format-agnostic, so you can use XML, JSON, HTML etc).

But the SOAP will wrap the structure into a SOAP envelope (follows an XML standard). The complexity of the SOAP envelope is based on the used message version and additional Web Service protocols. SOAP is generally transport-agnostic, meaning you don't necessarily need to use HTTP.

It can be pointed out that SOAP was designed for a distributed computing environment whereas REST was designed for a point-to-point environment.

I wonder if it is OK to say that while SOAP gives more security, REST-based API s will be easier on the resources and more scalable? As an example, Twitter, Facebook, Google Drive, Blogger, etc all have REST-based APIs that clients can consume.

Comment: The basic SOAP envelope is a pretty minimal wrapper. It's only when starting to get into WS-Security and such that it starts to becomes .. extra fun.

Comment: If you're going to start doing things like message routing and message-level security, you're going to have _just as much “fun”_ with REST as with SOAP.

Comment: @DonalFellows But are you ever going to do stuff like that with REST? Or rather, if you try to do that with REST, you're maybe doing it wrong, because wouldn't that be like... starting to do message routing and message level security with... SQL or something? (Note: not implying that SQL and REST are otherwise related in any way.) Not an expert in the subject, so maybe I'm wrong about this.

Answer (score 0):

Generally `REST` reduces the size and scope of request payloads by mapping request semantics to the underlying HTTP protocol. For example, `SOAP` will usually add an envelope (of varying complexity) which utilizes a `WSDL` (a contract) for both request and response types and service mappings. REST will just use [POST, GET, etc](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) to a URL with some HTTP encoded parameters and thus lacks an enforced contract.

Answer (score 0):

There are several aspects of lightweight. SOAP is XML only, while REST allows you to send any payload, such as JSON which is less verbose and simpler than XML. Generally speaking, it takes less memory and less bandwidth to deal with JSON than XML.

On another level, using SOAP you typically describe everything as services. So, you need to define a message schema/structure for each verb and noun i.e. "CreateOrder". In REST, you use the predefined HTTP methods such as POST and put the noun/"resource" in the URI which uses already existing constructs on the HTTP level - not reinventing them in XML.

Then there is the effort it takes to adapt to change. A small change in SOAP requires you to redefine the schema, redefine the wsdl and handle versions. In rest, in the best of worlds, there is a degree of dynamic coded into the API (links to referenced resources, among other things), so that some changes can be implemented and takes effect directly.

All the heavy weight strictness of SOAP of course has a valid reason for existence. It's less likely two implementations have different interpretations of the API, than in a loosely defined REST API. SOAP also allows you to implement skeleton code in various languages based on a WSDL. In some complex scenarios, this is actually almost the only productive way to work with SOAP. Marshalling and unmarshalling between objects and serialized XML is rather heavy and adds to the heavyness of SOAP.